# Angular redirects keeps going back to login after authentication passes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to finish off the authentication page but the AuthGuard keeps sending me back to login component even after all the checks returns true.

It should redirect user to dashboard but it send it back to login page.

authguard service

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated() === false) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: IndexDashboardComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]}
];
```

Login function based in User class

```
login(email, password) {
    const uri  = environment.apiUrl + '/api/auth/login';
    const body = {
      email:    email,
      password: password
    }

    this.http.post<LoginDataModel>(uri, body)
        .subscribe(async response => {
                     localStorage.setItem('token', response.token_type + ': ' + response.access_token);
                     localStorage.setItem('token_expiry', response.expires_at);
                     await this.router.navigate([ 'dashboard' ]);
                   }
        );
  }
```

Auth Service Class

```
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token       = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const tokenExpiry = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('token_expiry'));
    const now = new Date()
    const secondsSinceEpoch = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000)

    if (token) {
      return secondsSinceEpoch <= tokenExpiry;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Login Component

```
   constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        email:    '',
        password: '',
      }
    );

    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated() === true) {
      this.router.navigate([ '/dashboard' ]);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  async onSubmit(userData) {
    await (new User(this.http, this.router, this.authService)).login(userData.email, userData.password);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

This wildcard route gets triggered on all the routes except for "". Your auth guard doesn't get triggered at all. Make sure to put wildcard routes at the end of the array, because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy.